# How to Add and read Index to WinForm ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am working on .NET 4.0 WinForm Application. I need comboBox that I need to add with `range` & `IndexId` followed by when I choose value from dropdown then capture Id for processing instead of the string value.

I have list that I like to add in range

`List`

```
 var distinctPermissions = permissions.GroupBy(_ => _.LevelCategoryName).Select(_ => _.First()).Select(_ => new { _.UserLevelCategoryId, _.LevelCategoryName }).ToList();
```

I can just show string value by doing following code;

```
 var distinctPermissions = permissions.GroupBy(_ => _.LevelCategoryName).Select(_ => _.First()).Select(_ => _.LevelCategoryName ).ToList();

 var distinctPermissionNamesList = distinctPermissions.ToArray<string>();

 SystemAComboBox.Items.AddRange(distinctPermissionNamesList);
```

That is how I am reading drop down string value that I need to pick index instead of string

```
var systemAComboBox = SystemAComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

[image]

`ComboBox`

```
SystemAComboBox.Items.AddRange(distinctPermissionNamesList);
```

Comment: for me this is a beautiful example of when not to use the var keyword.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/programmatically-binding-datasource-to-combobox-in-multiple/

Comment: `systemAComboBox.DisplayMember = "LevelCategoryName"; systemAComboBox.ValueMember = "UserLevelCategoryId"; systemAComboBox.DataSource = distinctPermissions;`  -- `UserLevelCategoryId` is the SelectedValue.

Answer (score 1):

you can write this

```
    class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public override string ToString()=>Name;
      
    }
    var distinctPermissions = permissions.GroupBy(_ => _.LevelCategoryName).Select(_ => _.First()).Select(_ => new ComboBoxItem{ Id = _.UserLevelCategoryId,Name= _.LevelCategoryName }).ToList();
    foreach(var item in distinctPermissions){
        SystemAComboBox.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

when you select a item

```
ComboBoxItem item = SystemAComboBox.SelectedItem as SystemAComboBox;
```